# creation of a vector out of matrixes using a loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector

Im trying to create a vector by combining multiple matrixes using a loop.
If I do it manually it looks like this:

```
vector = c(
           matrix(labels[1],ccl$size[1]), 
           matrix(labels[2],ccl$size[2]), 
           matrix(labels[3],ccl$size[3]),
           matrix(labels[4],ccl$size[4]),
           matrix(labels[5],ccl$size[5]))
```

labels is a vector with a given number of elements, as is ccl$size. the problem is that no loop seems to accept any substring of the function as a valuable input.

edit: I tried

```
c(for(i in repeats) 
{matrix(labels[i],ccl$size[i]),}
)
```

edit2:

inputs
labels: c(2,1,3)

ccl$size: c(12,10,7)

desired output
c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)

Comment: Then are you just looking for `rep`?

Comment: In other words, simply `rep(labels, ccl$size)`

Comment: You need to learn that the first argument to 'matrix' are the Values and the second arg is the number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `rep`:

```
v1 <- c(2,1,3)
v2 <- c(12, 10, 7)

rep(v1, v2)
#  [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```